# project cxf installed on JBoss Fuse but still "no services have been found"

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jbossfuse

I'm trying to learn how to make a REST service with cxf and JBoss Fuse. After the successful installation of the service on the server, I try to see the list of the installed cxf services on http://localhost:8181/cxf, getting the expression "No services have been found". Some one know why no services didn't show up and how can I show it?
The code that I'm using as test is the one in this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jboss_fuse/jboss_fuse_rest_web_services.htm, starting from the maven project org.apache.cxf cxf-http-basic

Edit 1: After following the helpful rewrite guide of Abolfazl I installed and started again the service.
This time doing osgi:list I get

```
[ 320] [Active     ] [Failure     ] [       ] [   80] mvn:com.tuts.abhinav/rest-service/1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

While doing log:display I get

```
2017-05-23 09:44:36,969 | ERROR | l Console Thread | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 23 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.5 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle null/0.0.0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)[:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.readDirectives(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:214)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:296)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:270)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:294)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:263)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:253)
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1127)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:696)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:484)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4429)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2100)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:963)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.StartBundle.doExecute(StartBundle.java:37)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.osgi.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:37)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:38)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler$1.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:54)[19:org.apache.aries.proxy.impl:1.0.5]
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:119)[19:org.apache.aries.proxy.impl:1.0.5]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.commands.$BlueprintCommand417451938.execute(Unknown Source)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:92)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:197)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.DelayedStarted.run(DelayedStarted.java:79)[38:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:2.4.0.redhat-630187]
```

Comment: Did you check console logs after installing and starting bundle? please type "list" command in jboss fuse console and check if bundle state is "active".

Comment: After installing and running the bundle there are no errors in the logs, like the service is working fine. When I check on osgi:list the state of the bundle is active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above sample need some corrections as following:

1-In "Add Fuse Plugin Repositories" section in last line of the code, "<pluginRepositories>" must replace with </pluginRepositories>.

2-In "Add Build Instruction" section at line 6 of the code, "artifalctId" must replaces with "artifactId".

Correct steps for create and deploy above sample are as following:

1-Create a simple Maven quick-start project with following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.tuts.abhinav -DartifactId=rest-service -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

2-Change project structure until you have following structure:
[image: Project Structure]

3-"UserService.java" class must have following content:

```
package com.tuts;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/UserService_1")
public class UserService {
   @GET
   @Path("/get_data")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

   public String getUser() {
      String reponse = "This is standard response from REST";
      return reponse;
   }
}
```

4-"blueprint.xml" file should have following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0     http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd    http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs     http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxrs.xsd">
    <jaxrs:server address="/users" id="service">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref component-id="userService"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
    <bean class="com.tuts.UserService" id="userService"/>
</blueprint>
```

5-"pom.xml" file should have following content:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.tuts.abhinav</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-service</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>rest-service</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.specs.jsr311-api-1.1.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix</groupId>
        <artifactId>servicemix-http</artifactId>
        <version>2013.01</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>fusesource.m2</id>
        <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>

        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>

    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>fusesource.ea</id>
        <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>fusesource.m2</id>
        <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>

        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>

            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>rest-example-database-post-method
                    </Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Import-Package>* </Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

6-You can install project with following command:

```
mvn install
```

7-Finally, you can deploy project bundle in karaf with following command:

```
osgi:install -s mvn:com.tuts.abhinav/rest-service/1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

After that your service must available at http://localhost:8181/cxf url:

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still have some problem to install the service on the fuse. After the installation and doing osgi:list I get:
[ 320] [Active ] [Failure ] [ ] [ 80] mvn:com.tuts.abhinav/rest-service/1.0-SNAPSHOT.
Controlling on the log it say:
2017-05-22 17:19:09,545 | ERROR | l Console Thread | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 23 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.5 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle null/0.0.0

Comment: Please execute "log:display" command and print your exception here.

Comment: in the comments there is not enough space, I'm going to edit the post and write it there

Comment: Please be sure your MANIFEST.MF contains :"Manifest-Version: 1.0" at first line and "Class-Path:" at second line.

Comment: the MANIFEST.MF is fine, both the rows are as you said

Comment: Please zip your project and email to me: abhash2009@gmail.com

Comment: You need 3 changes in your project: 1-In your blueprint.xml file, change "XMLschema" to "XMLSchema", 2-In your pom.xml file, line 6, change "jar" to "bundle", and 3-In your pom.xml file, dependencies section, add cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs as above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this REST example from Fuse instead? It uses JBoss Fuse 6.3:

https://github.com/jboss-fuse/quickstarts/tree/master/cxf/rest

Comment: After Installing and starting your example I can see your service on the http://localhost:8181/cxf, but I still didn't understand why I can't see the other example I was using.